# How to use Dependancy Injection when dependant class is not known at Registration?

Tags: dependency-injection, unity-container

I have few questions about Dependency Injection using Unity Framework
1>Does each class always need default constructor?
2>How do we register a class whose dependent class is not known at the time of registration but it will become avialble at latter stage.
3>Once this dependent class is available at latter stage, how do i assign it back

for example, I dont know the Address of the customer at the time of registration, but the address will be known at latter stage in the flow. I Register the Customer class with Unity container in Global.ascx file (Application Start) where i dont know the Address.

```
public class Customer : IPerson<Customer>
{
    private Address _address;

    public Customer(Address address)
    {
        _address = address;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using dependency injection on entities is the typical thing *not* to do. Entities, such as `Customer` and `Person` are usually much shorter lived objects that contain data instead of behavior and are therefore not good candidates for dependency injection.

In general, you should use some sort of factory for creating those short lived objects that cannot be managed by a container, or in your case, use the [repository pattern](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html). Inject an `ICustomerRepository` into services that need to deal with `Customers`.

To answer your other questions:

> Does each class always need default constructor?

No, it does not. As a general guideline it is best to have a single public constructor for classes that are used as service components (the classes in your system that contain behavior), but it doesn't have to be the default constructor.

> How do we register a class whose dependent class is not known at the
>   time of registration but it will become avialble at latter stage.

In general, you would inject a factory, or in some cases you could inject a proxy that knows how to create the real object later on.